# How to make server automatically send data back to connected client

Tags: java, rmi

I'm using Java RMI for networking programming between client and server. Client connects to server, invoke method and receive is easily solved by RMI Technology. But now I have this problem : the server will remember that registered client, and at sometime, server will return data back to that client by method A.

So my questions are:

- How to let server remember registered client and send back data to that client when needed?
- How to let client know that server is sending method A, not method B?

Comment: Are client and server on the same local network or is the client behind a firewall/nat box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1) Make a UnicastRemoteObject on the client and send it to the server. (server-push)

Option 2) Have the server store the data and have the client call a method to pick it up at regular intervals. (client-polling)